# Unable to start Genymotion virtual device. Unable to initialize OpenGl renderer library. Check if the video card support OpenGL 2.0

Tags: opengl, genymotion

I have installed both Virtual Box and genymotion and virtual device.

When I start virtual device GalaxyS3 it gives me this error:

```
Unable to start Genymotion virtual device. 
Unable to initialize OpenGl renderer library. 
Check if the video card support OpenGL 2.0
```

I use windows7.

How can I update my video card?

Comment: After I updated Videoadapter NVIDIA GeForce genimotion started working. To update videoadapter : right click on My Computer icon - select Properties and choose Device Manager on left pane. Finally select NVIDIA Geforce right click on it and choose Update driver

Comment: The canonical way to give self-answers is to write them as an actual answer and later on accept that one.

Comment: you can update driver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error

Answer (score -1):

I had this error with the latest Geforce 760m mobile drivers I got from my laptop manufacturer. In the end, what worked for me was letting the windows wizard find drivers online for my card.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i solved this in my intel core i3 :

Goto control panle > System and Security > Windows Update > Check for updates

Now in the selected update list make sure to check the options 
Intel Corporation - Graphics AdapterWDDM1.1,Graphics Adapter WDDM1.2, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3 -Intel(R)HD Graphics
and  Intel - Other hardware -Intel(R) Management Engine Interface.

After updating genymotion works as expected.